# How to split tuple with parentheses in Python?

Tags: python, networkx

I have built-in tuple which looks like `(u,v)`. They are generated by Networkx and they show links in a graph. I make a list out of the called `link_list`.

I have to split the tuple such that the outcome would be: `u , v`

I tried `divmod` but it doesn't give the right answer.

```
for link in link_list:
    u,v = divmod(*link)
    print u,v
```

Comment: Please show an example of this "not working".

Comment: Can you expand further on what you expect for a right answer? For example, if I gave you a tuple `(23 ,42)`, what output do you expect, and what output would your code give you currently?

Comment: Just FYI, `divmod` returns the quotient and remainder when division is performed on its arguments. `q, r = divmod(x,y)` is equivalent to `q, r = x/y, x%y`.

Comment: The answer was simple. I was confused!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple:

```
for link in link_list:
    u, v = link
    print u, v
```

It's called [sequence unpacking](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

Answer (score 9):

you can get the tuple into individual variables in the for statement as following:

```
for u,v in link_list:
     print u,v
```

Comment: Alas, the shortest and most pythonic solution is the least voted. (As of now.)

Comment: @Buttons840 the other nearly identical answer contained a link to the docs which is going to teach people to fish.  That is probably why it was accepted instead of this answer.

Comment: @istruble Good point.  That answer also received an upvote from me.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a tuple `(x,y)`, and you wish to destructure it to two variables, the syntax is simply:

```
u,v = (x,y)
```

Comment: I don't get it. If you already have `x` and `y`, you can just use `u,v = x,y`. If you have a tuple `link`, then you do `u,v = link`. You never need the construct you posted in your answer.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: imagine that the tuple `(x,y)` has been assigned to a variable, or perhaps is the return value of a function call.

Comment: Then use that variable or the function call directly. The example you're showing is not useful.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: At least three other users disagree with you.

Comment: I wouldn't make too much of it. Yesterday, eight users upvoted one of my answers which then turned out to be wrong. :)