# Visually Representing X and Y Values

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a list of (x,y) values that are in a list like [(x,y),(x,y),(x,y)....]. I feel like there is a solution in matplotlib, but I couldn't quite get there because of my formatting. I would like to plot it as a histogram or line plot. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could try something like this ([also see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806101/how-to-split-tuple-with-parentheses-in-python)):

```
import numpy as np:
xs=[]; ys=[]
for x,y in xy_list:
  xs.append(x)
  ys.append(y)
xs=np.asarray(xs)
ys=np.asarray(ys)
plot(xs,ys,'ro')
```

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it should work. Cheers, Trond

Comment: Nice, this is basically an implementation of `zip`.

Answer (score 7):

You can quite easily convert a list of `(x, y)` tuples into a list of two tuples of x- and y- coordinates using the * ('splat') operator (see also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917522/unzipping-and-the-operator)):

```
>>> zip(*[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9)])
[(0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 4, 9)]
```

And then, you can use the * operator again to unpack those arguments into `plt.plot`

```
>>> plt.plot(*zip(*[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9)]))
```

or even `plt.bar`

```
>>> plt.bar(*zip(*[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9)]))
```